# Wicket invalidate session & login on same event

Tags: session, authentication, wicket

When I try to log in while I'm already logged in, wicket gives me a LoginException; Additional Logins are not allowed. This makes sense of course.

What I want to do, is invalidate the session if there is already a user logged in, and log in in the same event.

```
if (((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).isUserAuthenticated()) {
   ((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).invalidateNow();
}
((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).login(secureLoginContext);
```

It seems invalidateNow is completed after the onSubmit event, because Wicket still gives me the same LoginException.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to log in again? Are you trying to log in with different credentials?

I have once written a panel where a user (already logged in) could log in as another user if he had sufficient rights. I ran into a similar problem and fixed it by forcing wicket to make a new session with `ThreadContext.setSession(null)`.

So you code would become:

```
if (((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).isUserAuthenticated()) {
   ((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).invalidateNow();
   ThreadContext.setSession(null);
}
((AuthenticatedWebSession) getSession()).login(secureLoginContext);
```